# PHP Obfuscate - Different Values

Tags: php

I'm trying to obfuscate and ID (Ex: 1) with different value.

So if I obfuscate 1 it may give me different values as ADHU6767asD or hiuy76FY and when I will un-obfuscate it, it will give 1.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

** EDIT :

When I access to a page of my php application (page.php?id=1) where 1 load specific information from the database, I want to obfuscate this is, to an alphanumeric string.

Neither I want the obfuscated string to always have the same value (ex : 1 is ALWAYS ABC543)
I'm also not interested to keep the obfuscated value into a database­.

Comment: Can you add some background on what you need this for and how secure it needs to be?

Comment: Just how obfuscated do you want to go? Cereal box decoder ring? rot13? AES? For simple obfuscation, `base64_encode(1)` -> `MQ==`.

Comment: According to the question, the obfuscation should be able to have many obfuscations for the same value.

Comment: Well, I would prefer if possible only letters and numbers, security is not really important, I simply don't want too often the same number having the same obfuscated ID

Yes Hakre.

Comment: This isnt obfuscation, it is encryption.

Comment: This service is pretty handy: [CodeEclipse](http://codeeclipse.com/)

Comment: @sberry2A is right; with your last requirement comes a whole slew of heavy lifting required to rotate your obfuscation method, which makes this de facto encryption.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice example by Ray Morgan of creating a tamper-proof user-id obfuscation scheme that does not require database storage of the id's encoded form :

- http://raymorgan.net/web-development/how-to-obfuscate-integer-ids/

Another approach would be to use symmetric (bi-directional) encryption (concat'ing id with a salt) with AES...

Answer (score 0):

The obfuscation protocol could use filename and/or function name as a salt for the obfuscation that will happen. That way you would only see the same IDs in the same file or function and you can have a repeatable process. Otherwise you would have to have many different ways for keeping track of how you obfuscated each file or function.

Comment: Good idea, I'm searching for something more simpler, but if nothing comes up, I think I will use your solution.